# Strategies to sync mongoDB and couchDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, couchdb, pouchdb

What are some strategies to sync data between these two?

The current scenario is a web app that works with MongoDB, mongoose and node, and a mobile app that uses pouchDB and syncs against CouchDB server, but how can MongoDB server and CouchDB server be in sync when data changes in any of them?

I tried with some trigger when something changes in any of them, but it would be an infinite cycle because: MongoDB DocX changes --> CouchDB update DocX ---> MongoDB update DocX because it changed in CouchDB, and again ----> CouchDB update document DocX because it changed in MongoDB

So, how are some good strategies to do something like this?

Comment: If you need syncing, why use mongo instead of couch?

Comment: Because the web app and the mobile app has been already created with that technology stack

Comment: Got it. Hopefully you get some good suggestions. Personally I would then add refactoring the web app to use couch. Then compare

Comment: Still nothing.
I've been trying to use nodejs Event emitters to do this, and lodash object comparison to achieve what documents have to be updated...